# What is the difference between the two definitions?

Tags: c#

```
string a = "var";
string b = new string("var");
```

I also have an extra question,
How do I access the string type variable in the 1st definition without allocating space in the heap?

Comment: How about: In .NETs that don't have a ReadOnlySpan, the second isn't valid?

Comment: please _no extra questions_ - one question per post. also: in the second line, you instantiate a string _with another string as source_. welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

## .NET Framework 4.8:

The first one compiles; the second one doesn't, producing a CS1503 error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char*'

That is because the `String` class does not have a constructor which accepts a `string` parameter.

## .NET Core 2.1 and later

The first one assigns the literal to a string variable. The second one implicitly casts the string to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, then calls the `String` constructor which accepts a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` instance, which copies the characters from the original string to a new string, doubling the memory usage.

---

As to your second question, since the `String` is a reference type, you cannot allocate an instance without allocating space in the heap.